# Passing arbitrary arguments to invocked methods with Google C++ Mocking Framework (Google Mock) (V1.5)

Tags: c++, unit-testing, parameters, mocking, googlemock

I have a mock method. When it is called, I'd like it to call another function before calling its normal behavior. Something like :

```
EXPECT_CALL(*my_obj, MockedMethod(_,_,_,_,_,_))
    .WillOnce(DoAll(
        Invoke(my_obj, &SomeAdditionalMethodIWantToCall),
        Invoke(my_obj, &DefaultBehavior),
        ));
```

The only problem is that `SomeAdditionalMethodIWantToCall` expects parameter that not at all related to the one provided to `MockedMethod`. I'd like to be able to give them but I am struggling with the syntax. I wish there was something like (in fake syntax) :

```
EXPECT_CALL(*my_obj, MockedMethod(_,_,_,_,_,_))
    .WillOnce(DoAll(
        Invoke(my_obj, &SomeAdditionalMethodIWantToCall, arg1, arg2, arg3),
        Invoke(my_obj, &DefaultBehavior),
        ));
```

I have looked for such a thing in the documentation without any success.

In [Using a Function or a Functor as an Action](https://code.google.com/p/googlemock/wiki/V1_5_CheatSheet#Using_a_Function_or_a_Functor_as_an_Action), we have :

- `Invoke(f)`, `Invoke(object_pointer, &class::method)`, `InvokeWithoutArgs(f)`, `InvokeWithoutArgs(object_pointer, &class::method)` which will just forward (or not) the parameter provided to the mocked function when it is called.
- `InvokeArgument<N>(arg1, arg2, ..., argk)` seems to be for calling one of the parameter.

In [Composite Actions](https://code.google.com/p/googlemock/wiki/V1_5_CheatSheet#Composite_Actions)

- `WithArg<N>(a)` and `WithArgs<N1, N2, ..., Nk>(a)` seem to be to select which parameters from the original function get forwarded.

I guess I am missing something quite obvious but I am a bit stuck here so any suggestion will help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One possible option would be to save the values of the arguments to class variables using the `Assign` action and then invoke the other function using a helper.  Use the following expectation:

```
EXPECT_CALL(*my_obj, MockedMethod(_,_,_,_,_,_))
    .WillOnce(DoAll(
        Assign(&classVariable1, arg1),
        Assign(&classVariable2, arg2),
        Assign(&classVariable3, arg3),
        InvokeWithoutArgs(my_obj, &MyClass::SomeAdditionalMethodIWantToCallHelper),
        Invoke(my_obj, &MyClass::DefaultBehavior),
        ));
```

Then define your helper function as follows:

```
void MyClass::SomeAdditionalMethodIWantToCallHelper()
{
    SomeAdditionalMethodIWantToCall(classVariable1, classVariable2, classVariable3);
}
```

**Edit**

Another possible option is to write a custom action that takes in a pointer to a member function along with the arguments you wish to pass to it.  This is closer to what you originally desired for syntax.  Here is the custom action:

```
ACTION_P5(InvokeUnrelatedFunction, classPointer, pointerToMemberFunc,
          first, second, third)
{
    (classPointer->*pointerToMemberFunc)(first, second, third);
}
```

Here's how you would use it in an expectation:

```
EXPECT_CALL(*my_obj, MockedMethod(_,_,_,_,_,_))
    .WillOnce(DoAll(
        InvokeUnrelatedFunction(my_obj, &MyClass::SomeAdditionalMethodIWantToCall,
                                arg1, arg2, arg3),
        Invoke(my_obj, &MyClass::DefaultBehavior),
        ));
```

Comment: With the `InvokeUnrelatedFunction` action, all i get is a compiler error saying that `arg1` is not declared at the point where i try to invoke the action. What could be the cause of that?

Comment: @Martin As stated in the question, `arg1` is a "parameter not at all related to the one provided to `MockedMethod`."  If you want to pass the arguments from the `MockedMethod` to a function, you can just use `Invoke`.  You can also combine `Invoke` with `WithArgs`if you want to.  Refer to the Google Mock Cookbook for an example.

Comment: My compiler says some return value is required

Comment: @ChristopherPisz You likely need to add a `Return` clause.  For example: `EXPECT_CALL(...).WillOnce(DoAll(Invoke(...),Return(someValue)));`

Comment: yea, the return value is for the mocked method. However, I need to do the invoke AFTER the mocked method returns. :/ I don't see a way.

Answer (score 10):

If you are using c++11, you can use lambda-functions like this:

```
EXPECT_CALL(*my_obj, MockedMethod(_,_,_,_,_,_))
.WillOnce(DoAll(
    InvokeWithoutArgs([&]() { 
        my_obj->SomeAdditionalMethodIWantToCall(arg1, arg2, arg3); 
    },
    Invoke(my_obj, &DefaultBehavior)   
));
```

Comment: Very elegant! Thanks.

Comment: what is the method is private?